# iOS: Track user location

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I've used location services in many apps, but this new app has a problem on iOS 8.0 and up.  I am not getting the notification on the app's first load prompting to allow location services.  However, on my iOS 7.1 device I get the prompt.

Here is what I have in my appDelegate in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[self initializeRegionMonitoring];
```

And the initializeRegionMonitoring method is:

```
-(void) initializeRegionMonitoring {

NSLog(@"initialize region monitoring");

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;

// radius of region being monitored
CLLocationDistance radius = 25; // 20 metre sensitivity
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = 25.886099;
coordinate.longitude = -80.165124;

self.someRegion = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:coordinate radius:radius identifier:@"Qualex"];
self.someRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
self.someRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.someRegion];

// notify changes when the device has moved x meters
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 20; // or set to 20 meters
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

I also have set the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my info.plist, so there must be something I've forgotten, right?  Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**

I'm also registering for remote notifications at the same time, that's never been a problem before but I thought it might be some useful extra information.

Also, when terminated the app then re-run the notification to allow location services pops up, but goes away instantly.  Just flashes on the screen.  I have no idea why it would dismiss without clicking one of the options on the alert.

Comment: Did you intend to replace the instance of your `locationManager` in the `initializeRegionMonitoring` method? The second instance will never have `requestAlwaysAuthorization` called on it, which may be the source of your issue.

Comment: Did you really intend to use two different location managers like this?

Comment: @thelaws This shouldn't matter. Location authorization is global within the current app across all CLLocationManager instances. Once the user has granted always-on location access, all location managers will have that access

Comment: @n00neimp0rtant Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Do you prompt the user before or after the window is setup?

Comment: the second instance was definitely an accident.  I removed the second instance and now the prompt is showing up.  Still doesn't make sense after what @n00neimp0rtant pointed out

Comment: Since `requestAlwaysAuthorization` is an async call, it's possible that reassigning your `locationManager` releases the instance needed for the  callback (or something to that effect)

Comment: Interesting, you should post this as the answer. @thelaws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before iOS 8, you could request location permission simply by instantiating a CLLocationManager object and attempting to start location tracking. On iOS 8 and above, this does not present a permission prompt; you must request authorization manually with either the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` methods.

That being said, on iOS 8, if you call either of those methods, then the CLLocationManager instance on which you called it is released, the location permission prompt will dismiss itself. What's happening here is that you are creating a location manager, requesting permission (iOS starts to try to present the permission dialog), calling `initializeRegionMonitoring`, and setting the `self.locationManager` property to a new location manager instance. This causes the first one you created to get released by ARC, so the permission prompt is dismissed before it even gets a chance to appear.

Removing the line `self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];` in your `initializeRegionMonitoring` method should fix the issue.

Comment: AFAIK, this quirk of CLLocationManager and the authorization process is not documented, so +1 on your question :)